# java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, D:\neo4j\sampledb

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to create an app using `spring-data-neo4j`.

I have used all the necessary dependencies in `pom.xml`.

I have configured `dispatcher-servlet.xml` for `neo4j`.

During deployment, while the bean is initializing, I am getting the following error.

```
12:21:53.397 [localhost-startStop-1] 
ERROR o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration#
0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'graphDatabaseService' while setting bean property 'graphDatabaseService'; 

 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'graphDatabaseService': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation;

 nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, D:\neo4j\sampledb

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336) ~[spring-
beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108) ~[
spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.ja
va:1457) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1198
) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
 ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~
[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.j
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:spring-configured/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.sample" />
<tx:annotation-driven mode="proxy"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

<neo4j:config storeDirectory="D:\neo4j\sampledb" base-package="com.sample"/>
```